# Comparing Properties in hasMany Criteria

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain classes like so:

```
class Person {
    Team team
    static hasMany = [history: PersonHistory]
}

class PersonHistory {
    Team team
    Person person
}
```

Now I would like to create a criteria that pulls back all the 'persons' who have a PersonHistory instance with a different team.

Something along the lines of:

```
    def c = Person.createCriteria()
    def experiment = c.list {
        history {
            neProperty("team", history.team)    
        }
    }
```

However this is throwing (because of the history.team):

```
Missing Property Exception 
No such property: history for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

Can I do this inside one criteria query? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test it but I think this should work:

```
Person.withCriteria {
    createAlias 'history', 'h'
    ne 'team', h.team
}
```

You have to create an alias for the join with history.

**EDIT:**

Now I got it! With the following sample data:

```
def t1 = new Team(name: 'team 1').save()
def t2 = new Team(name: 'team 2').save()
def t3 = new Team(name: 'team 3').save()

def p1 = new Person(team: t1).save()
def p2 = new Person(team: t1).save()
def p3 = new Person(team: t2).save()
def p4 = new Person(team: t2).save()
def p5 = new Person(team: t3).save()

def ph1 = new PersonHistory(person: p1, team: t1).save()
def ph2 = new PersonHistory(person: p2, team: t3).save() // t3 instead of t1
def ph3 = new PersonHistory(person: p3, team: t2).save()
def ph4 = new PersonHistory(person: p4, team: t1).save() // t1 instead of t2
def ph5 = new PersonHistory(person: p5, team: t3).save(flush: true)
```

Now you can execute the following criteria:

```
List<Person> persons = PersonHistory.withCriteria {
    createAlias 'person', 'p'
    neProperty 'p.team', 'team'

    projections {
        property 'person'
    }
}
```

That will return the correct persons `p2` and `p4`

Comment: This threw the same error but referencing 'h' instead of history